# Open form based on text value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking to try and have a text box that i type in a number and i want it to open another form based on that number. So i have form frmNonMgr that i type a number in the text field txtPhone and i want it to open frmFolder_Tabs to the record that relates to that number. [Phone] in the employees table are unique and you cannot have two of the same, when ive gotten it to work its just opening the last record or a blank record.

```
Private Sub btnFolder_Click()

If IsNull(Me.txtPhone) Then

MsgBox "Please enter a Phone"

Me.txtPhone.SetFocus

Else

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmFolder_Tabs", , , "[Phone]='" & Me.txtPhone

DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmNonMgr"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The condition is missing the closing quote `"[Phone]='" & Me.txtPhone & "'"`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to store phone number to a variable and then close the active form first. Then open your target form and use filter with stored variable. Also for string type data you need to enclose value with single quote what Kostas already mentioned. Try below codes.

```
Private Sub btnFolder_Click()
Dim strPhone As String
    If IsNull(Me.txtPhone) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a Phone"
        Me.txtPhone.SetFocus
    Else
        strPhone = Me.txtPhone
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmFolder_Tabs", , , "[Phone]='" & strPhone & "'"
    End If
End Sub
```